# ASP.NET eval ternary visibility of control in gridview

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a booking button that I want to make invisible on a datasource value being returned true. Why is it telling me server tag is poorly formed ?

Both the following below do not work. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Booker" runat="server" Height="48px" Text="" Width="48px" Visible="<%# Eval("in_use").ToString() != "True" ? "true" : "false"%>" class="btn btn_n"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></asp:LinkButton>
```

or

````
<asp:LinkButton ID="Booker" runat="server" Height="48px" Text="" Width="48px" Visible="<%# Eval("in_use").ToString() != "True" ? true : false%>" class="btn btn_n"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></asp:LinkButton>```
````

Comment: double quotes is the problem and you can try like this as well             
Visible='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("in_use").ToString())%>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is in_use a Boolean? If so then just set visible to be the opposite. !Eval("in_use"). You may have to cast the eval to a bool first. The main thing is your double quotes are probably confusing it. 
Try:
 Visible='<%# Eval("in_use").ToString() != "True" ? true : false%>'

It's rather fussy since your double quotes are possible terminating the attribute. The parser gets really finicky with this stuff.

Comment: Nice, sorry it was something so simple... but that did seem to work thank you.